# Which event fire on address change in Magento 1 Admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, address

After place new order by customer, If Admin change shipping address of customer from Sales-> Orders then I want to know which event fire while changing address, so that I can call my function in observer.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events are `sales_order_address_save_before` or `sales_order_address_save_after` depending on when you need to call your custom code.

These events are fired in the backend and frontend also.
Maybe you want to place your event inside the `adminhtml` area to make it fire only when in backend.